# Create database on docker-compose startup

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I would like to create a MySQL database using environment variables in docker-compose.yml file, but it is not working. I have the following code:

```
# The Database
database:
  image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  ports:
    - "33061:3306"
```

Could someone explain the function of this vars?

Answer (score 152):

There is also an option to provide an init file for `mysql` container which will be applied each time a container is created.

```
database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
```

Such file (`init.sql`) could contain your initial database structure and data - for example:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dev;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
USE dev;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (...);
```

Comment: /data/application/init.sql this file should be located in the host machine? or inside mysql container?

Comment: @MadhanAyyasamy see the updated answer. Since `/data/application/init.sql` is an argument to mysql which runs in the container, the path has to be "internal" too. The file can get there by being bind mounted.

Comment: can i run multiple sql file?

Comment: This will result in a **directory** called `/data/application/init.sql` on the container, _unless_ the file already exists on container. About mounting a host file to appear as a file in the container read about **bind mounts** at the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: Where to put my init.sql file locally?

Comment: @Matley the volume paths inside `docker-compose.yml` are relative to that file, so if it's in root project directory and our mount contains `./init.sql:/data/application/init.sql` then the `init.sql` file has to also be in the root directory

Comment: beautiful way to create two databases upon starting a docker-compose

Answer (score 57):

The database is probably already initialized and the configuration is stored in `/var/lib/mysql`. Since you defined a volume for that location the config will survive a restart. The MySQL image will not reconfigure the database over and over again, it only does this once.

```
volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

If your database is empty you can reset the database by performing `docker-compose down -v` where the `-v` removes the volumes defined in the volume section. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/. On the next `docker-compose up` the MySQL image will start fresh and will initialize the database with the configuration you've provided throug the environment section.

Comment: Oh yeah! thank you very much, it must was that because now it is getting values from env. vars.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I couldn't import my database sql gz file automatically since volume was already created without it the first time. The -v argument fixed this.

Comment: Oh my days this was so useful. I spent the best part of a whole work day trying to figure out why docker up wasn't creating the DB. (It had been deleted). This fixed it. Surprisingly doing `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`, `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` and `docker rmi $(docker images -q)` did NOT solve this. I would've thought nuking everything would have worked.

Answer (score 37):

The official MySQL docker image added support for init scripts in their base image. They document the feature under their "Initializing a fresh instance" on the Docker Hub page.

Here are the steps I took to solve creating multiple database and users in the MySQL docker image:

1. Create the init file (the Docker image recognizes .sh, .sql, and .sql.gz files) named `setup.sql` in the local directory named `.docker`
2. Place the commands inside `setup.sql` (see below for an example)
3. Mount the setup script into the directory `f` within the `docker-compose.yaml` file (see below for an example)
4. Run `docker-compose up -d` and MySQL will run the code inside `setup.sql`

> Note: the script will run files alphabetically, so keep that in mind.

**Example docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.5"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SomeRootPassword1!
            MYSQL_USER: someuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: Password1!
            MYSQL_DATABASE: somedatabase
        volumes:
            - .docker/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    db_data:
```

**Example setup.sql**

```
-- create the databases
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS projectone;

-- create the users for each database
CREATE USER 'projectoneuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, INDEX, LOCK TABLES, REFERENCES, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, SELECT, INSERT ON `projectone`.* TO 'projectoneuser'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Doesnt work, I get the error: myflashcards_db | 2020-04-08T18:51:57.851680Z 1 [ERROR] Failed to open the bootstrap file /data/application/init.sql
myflashcards_db | 2020-04-08T18:51:57.851718Z 1 [ERROR] 1105  Bootstrap file error, return code (0). Nearest query: 'SET @@sql_log_bin = @sql_log_bin;

Comment: This answer works when you need to grant privileges to users other than root, whether they are created using the environmental variable MYSQL_USER or in the setup.sql file.

Answer (score 25):

Answering your question ...

One thing I use to do when building a new docker container is understand what the image I pull from does when is builded.

In your docker-compose.yml tou have this

```
# The Database
database:
  image: mysql:5.7
```

This is the image you pull from, "mysql:5.7"

Dockerhub is a repository where you can find info of this images.

Do a google search "mysql:5.7 dockerhub"

First result is https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

There you have your image 5.7, if you click on 5.7 you have this

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/607b2a65aa76adf495730b9f7e6f28f146a9f95f/5.7/Dockerfile

Which is the Dockerfile from the image, you can have a look at interesting things that happen when building the image.

One of this is ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

This is the file that got executed when image is ready

I you go one level up in the repo you will see this file

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/607b2a65aa76adf495730b9f7e6f28f146a9f95f/5.7

The you can see your environment variables being used to create new database etc...

```
file_env 'MYSQL_DATABASE'
        if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
            echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\` ;" | "${mysql[@]}"
            mysql+=( "$MYSQL_DATABASE" )
fi
```

Answer (score 18):

For version 2 of docker-compose you'll `.yml` or `.yaml` can look like this:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
 dbdata:

services:
 mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: mysql
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead
    - MYSQL_USER=root
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
  ports:
    - "33061:3306"
```

start it with `docker-compose up -d`
and check:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
a3567fb78d0d        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:33061->3306/tcp   mysql

docker exec -it a3567fb78d0d bash
root@a3567fb78d0d:/# mysql -u root -p homestead
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.7.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| homestead          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your volume will be persisted in docker volume `nameoffolder_dbdata` (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/...`)

Comment: That is no exactly that i asking but it is interesting. I wonder if the envinronment vars are to create the database as well. Because in the docker-compose.yml figure the database name, why?

Comment: I don't fully understand your reply/question but yes, the env var's are creating a database with the name homestead. Check my answer when I perform show databases. You see the homestead db, also I'm authenticating on that db (-p)

Comment: I already have the container. I want to create the database for the container. Can you please tell me that how to create the docker-compose file for the container?

Comment: Use an image which contains a database in the container like mysql or postgres? if you want to install your own db you have to write a Dockerfile and build the image in docker-compose

Answer (score 11):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to to have a container with a specific database in it. Like have a MySQL container with `CREATE DATABASE mydb`, etc. already executed. If so you need to use `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`:
https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/#docker-secrets

When the official MySQL container is started for the first time, a new database will be created first. Then it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. So all you need to do is create `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory and put your initialisation script there.

Answer (score 10):

The "Initializing a fresh instance" here https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ states to copy all .sql,.sh,.sql.gz files into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder. Below is the docker-compose file that I am using for plenty of my projects and all working fine with latest version of MySQL

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:   
  mysql:
      environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=root
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme
          - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=changeme
      command: 
         - --table_definition_cache=100
         - --performance_schema=0
         - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
         - --innodb_use_native_aio=0
      volumes: 
          - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      container_name: mysqldb
      image: mysql
```

and my init folder has an `init.sql` file containing the entire SQL data dump that I need to recreate when my container starts.

Below commands are used to limit memory consumed by MySQL container to 100 MB:

```
         - --table_definition_cache=100
         - --performance_schema=0
```

NOTE: This doesn't persist your MySQL data if you wish to persist your data then use the below configuration

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:   
  mysql:
      environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=root
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme
          - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=changeme
      command: 
         - --table_definition_cache=100
         - --performance_schema=0
         - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
         - --innodb_use_native_aio=0
      volumes: 
          - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      container_name: mysqldb
      image: mysql
```

where `dbdata` is a folder you need to create on your host system.

Comment: good to know about how to persist data between restarts thanks

Answer (score 7):

This setup implies your database already exists. Otherwise you have to create it with an init script or manually.

Init scripts(any `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz` files) are expected in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder within your docker container.

All you have to do is to simply add this init script as a volume to your docker-compose file.

```
database:
 image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - ./init-script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-script.sql

  ...
```

Your `init-script.sql` file might look like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS some_name;
USE some_name;
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind if you want to docker-compose  automatically create database from MYSQL_DATABASE your data folder (**dbdata**) must be **empty**!

```
    # The Database
    database:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql   <--- check local dbdata is empty!
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead 

    etc...
```

No need initial scripts, just:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Clean dbdata

```
docker-compose up
```

./dbdata/homestead - exists

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of the [Mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

> MYSQL_DATABASE
> This variable is optional and allows you to specify the name of a database to be created on image startup. If a user/password was supplied (see below) then that user will be granted superuser access (corresponding to GRANT ALL) to this database.

So, just add it to your docker-compose.yml file:

```
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.29
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '[your-database-name]'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create database
your docker-compose.yml will looks like
if you want to use Dockerfile

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

your docker-compose.yml will looks like
if you want to use your image instead of Dockerfile

```
version: '3.1'   

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
```

if you want to store or preserve data of mysql then
must remember to add two lines in your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

after that use this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

now your data will persistent and will not be deleted even after using this command

```
docker-compose down
```

extra:- but if you want to delete all data then you will use

```
docker-compose down -v
```