# mySQL init scripts not running with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I wish to start docker-compose up with my mySQL database and run the init scripts.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    network_mode: host
    restart: always  
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: some_db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    volumes:
      - ./docker/images/sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1200:3306"
```

I added the volume to link my sql-scripts to the entrypoint but when I start the containers using docker-compose up, I do not see the entrypoint scripts being run. This is what my logs for the db container show:
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.28-1.1.13
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.28-1.1.13

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer here [Create database on docker-compose startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322033/create-database-on-docker-compose-startup)

The database was probably already initialized. The MySQL image does not reconfigure the database over and over again, it only does this once. To reset the database perform `docker-compose down -v` where the `-v` removes the volumes defined in the volume section.