# How to run a program after docker is built

Tags: mysql, docker

I am working to built a docker image that will make a mysql docker container. I have this little program that I wrote that will create the db I need and do some routine to push some data in it. The issue is that I need to program to execute automatically when the container is building.

The program works fine if I run it manually but never run when I try to run it in the dockerfile or in the docker-entrypoint.sh. It seems that when the container is running this script the server is not fully up or at least not accessible through localhost? I guess there is some other way to run custom programs after the docker container is built ? Or is the solution on the way I try to access the database ?

## Edit

So there is my docker compose file content

```
 db:
    build: ./databaseDocker
    volumes:
        - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'MyDatabaseName'
      MYSQL_USER: 'company_root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '12345'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123456'
    ports: 
        - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Dockerfile in ./databaseDocker folder

```
FROM mysql:5.7.34
COPY ./dbseeder /tmp/dbseeder 
WORKDIR /tmp/dbseeder
RUN chmod 777 .
COPY ./db_custom_init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 3306
```

the db_custom_init.sh file which contain the command I am running

```
./DBSeedApp Param1 Param2
```

The app is home written using .net core to seed data in the database based on some parameters. The app is trying to connect to database like so:

```
string connectionString = $"server={host};port={port};user={username};pwd={password};database={databaseName};";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
               
                 cmd.Connection = conn;
                 conn.Open();
                 //do stuff
                 conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

One solution I might look for which I don't like would be to seed the data to an external database and dump the SQL backup on the docker container for it to be executed directly through mysql cli.However, this method seems ineficient and I really would like to work directly with the docker mysql server.

## New attempt

I changed my init file for :

```
echo "Check DB!"
while ! mysqladmin ping -h localhost -u root -p123456; do
    echo "Wait ..."
    sleep 1
done
echo "DB ready!"
./DBSeedApp Param1 Param2
```

But no luck I also added this to my program:

```
 private void VerifyConnections()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = $"server={host};port={port};user={username};pwd={password};";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine($"Trying to connect to {host}");
                conn.Open();
                System.Console.WriteLine($"Connection successful to {host}");
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            System.Console.WriteLine($"Cannot connect to {host}");
        }
        
    }
```

But no luck it confirms me that it can't find the localhost db server. I also tried by specifying the db container name but doesn't work either.

## Got it working but...

I got it working using a dirty hack. I used an external mysql server to "build my seed" to then dump an sql file from this external server.

I ended up creating a dump argument on my program which tells it to connect to the external server, build the seed and then export it into an sql file.

Then I run this on my init.sh file

```
./dbseedapp DUMP param1 param2 ...
mysql -u root -p mydbname --binary-mode < /tmp/dbseeder/temp/dump.sql
```

I used [MysqlBackup.Net](https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net) to generate the sql file from the external mysql server.

I'd like to find an other solution but for now this is the best I came up with. If someone have a better idea... let me know.

Comment: check docker-compose

Comment: I'm using docker-compose... I don't get how this will help me ? Could you explain a little further ?

Comment: Could you post the shell script and the docker file? Its hard to identify what the problem is without seeing the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL init scripts not running with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657489/mysql-init-scripts-not-running-with-docker-compose)

Comment: Without knowing your exact problem, maybe one solution could be checking if your server is up and running. See [Dockerfile healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck).

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: I provided everything I could I hope I added everything you need to help me :) Let me know if I ca improve my question better.

Comment: one clarification, the program works perfectly when I execute it directly from the bash once the container is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using official MySQL image, this could help you.

When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions `.sh, .sql and .sql.gz` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order.

So if you want to push some data in the container just put a backup file `.sql` with the data in this directory, `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` when the container is started it will initialize the data

Comment: This is not my case I really need to use a program that will seed data into the database. The data can not be contained in sql files... I'll try to find a way to may be dump an SQL file but I will still need to execute the program prior to that.

Comment: @AlexandreSamson

Comment: @AlexandreSamson did you try

Comment: @AlexandreSamson sorry stack overflow mobile app is bad, my PC crashed . Did you try to run `docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld` wait for it to start and then run your program

Comment: That is a wonderful Idea... But I am not sure how to do it exactly. I'll try somthing

Comment: it didn't work as you can see in my latest attempt. Seems like only the command line tool is able to join the database server at this point.