# Why is my docker.compose file not creating my database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker.compose file and when I start it I want it to create a database with some tables.

My docker compose:

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqldb
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE # CAP_SYS_NICE
    # container_name: my_very_special_server
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password!
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password!
    volumes:
      - ./DbScripts/DumpTodoOnly.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/DumpTodoOnly.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: dev_pma
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3307
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8183:80
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: 
      context: ./BE
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.prod
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    links:
      - mysql
  client:
    container_name: FE
    build: 
      context: ./FE
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db_data:
```

project structure:

[image]

the actual sql file:

### -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.18, for Win64 (x86_64)

-- Host: localhost    Database: todo

---

-- Server version   8.0.18

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

### --
-- Table structure for table `todos`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `todos`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `todos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `todotext` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

### --
-- Table structure for table `users`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `Id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Password` binary(60) NOT NULL,
  `ChangedPassword` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ImageId` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SeqRef` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Email_UNIQUE` (`Email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=2;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

### --
-- Dumping routines for database 'todo'

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2022-03-16 20:20:30

When I run docker-compose up I see:

[image]

And in my php admin I dont see any users or todos table:

[image]

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this is somewhat not great to find an answer when you post but for those with similar issue:

Apperently When you run the docker-compose up command the database configuration gets stored and survices a restart. To make this I had to:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322033/create-database-on-docker-compose-startup)

Note @Sebastiaan Renkens answer