# Docker + MySql: Can't acces container

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I have a laravel app and I wanted to use a webserver + mysql database (here I used docker). But I have a very bad time trying to make it work. I tried at least 10 different docker-compose and I face the same problem :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'app.acti_app-network' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    # PHP-FPM - Service
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile

        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        working_dir: /var/www

        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-files/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

        networks:
            - app-network

    # NGINX - Service
    webserver:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true

        ports:
            - "8100:80"
            - "8143:443"

        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-files/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/

        networks:
            - app-network

    # MySql - Service
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'

        volumes:
            - mysqldbdata:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker-files/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf

        networks:
            - app-network

# Volumes
volumes:
    mysqldbdata:
        driver: local

# Networks
networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
```

I know this going to help. This is what Select Host Query returnig:

```
mysql> SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| localhost | mysql.infoschema |
| localhost | mysql.session    |
| localhost | mysql.sys        |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For better security, use root user only for administrative purpose and create another user with limited access for use by the application. For creating separate user, you can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59653823/93794