# Access denied to create a test database

Tags: docker, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

I don´t understand why user is allowed to create a dev database while he is not to create a test one.

At the root of my project :

docker-compose

```yaml
db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
    ports:
        - '127.0.0.1:3306:3306'
    volumes:
        - 'db:/var/lib/mysql'
```

.env :

```
DB_NAME=mydb
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
DB_USER=dev
DB_PASSWORD=dev
```

**In the app directory, I tried following scenarios :**

#### Scenario 1 :

Without .env.test and an overriden url from dev to test

doctrine.yaml :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: "%env(DB_VERSION)%"
```

test/doctrine.yaml :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname_suffix: _test
        profiling: true
```

.env :

```
APP_ENV=dev
DB_VERSION=5.7
DATABASE_URL=mysql://dev:dev@db:3306/mydb
```

#### Scenario 2 :

With the same config in both dev and test environments, except the database name

doctrine.yaml :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: "%env(DB_VERSION)%"
```

test/doctrine.yaml :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        profiling: true
```

.env :

```
APP_ENV=dev
DB_VERSION=5.7
DATABASE_URL=mysql://dev:dev@db:3306/mydb
```

.env.test :

```
APP_ENV=test
DB_VERSION=5.7
DATABASE_URL=mysql://dev:dev@db:3306/mydb_test
```

#### Scenario 3 :

With different variables in different environments

doctrine.yaml :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: "%env(DB_VERSION)%"
```

test/doctrine.yaml :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_TEST_URL)%'
        profiling: true
```

.env :

```
APP_ENV=dev
DB_VERSION=5.7
DATABASE_URL=mysql://dev:dev@db:3306/mydb
```

.env.test :

```
APP_ENV=test
DB_VERSION=5.7
DATABASE_TEST_URL=mysql://dev:dev@db:3306/mydb_test
```

#### Problem :

`docker compose run --rm myContainer doctrine:database:create` : the main database is created without problem

`docker compose run --rm myContainer doctrine:database:create --env=test` : I always get the following error :

> Could not create database `mydb_test` for connection named default
> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'dev'@'%' to database 'mydb_test'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create database on docker-compose startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322033/create-database-on-docker-compose-startup) Dev database is already created. Test database cannot be created as you do not login with root database account to create it.

Comment: I resolved the problem thanks to your comment. I put DATABASE_TEST_URL=mysql://root:root@db:3306/mydb_test in .env.test file. But is this a good practice ? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a good practice as you are connected as a root user on your database during your test. In production you aren't logged as root (and you shall not :) ), so some test can appears as successful, but be failing in prod environment. Did you try to create it as root, then to use it normally? On linux shell: `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@db:3306/mydb_test docker compose run --rm myContainer doctrine:database:create --env=test` then start your test.

Comment: I don't understand in the command you put how a `test` user can have rights to edit database while defining database url with `root` user :/

Comment: In the command, root user is only used to create database. The env variable (with root) is only applied on the first command, the command that creates database. Then, database created, you run your tests normally, without the root user.

Comment: The thing is : how could I declare a db user other than root in Symfony without having to call a script ? `user: "%env(DB_USER)%"  password: "%env(DB_PASSWORD)%"` in doctrine.yaml file is not working.